# How to Convert NFS into a Storage Class in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume, kubernetes-pod

I work in an media organisation where we deploy all our application on monolithic VMs but now we want move to kubernetes but we have major problem we have almost 40+NFS servers from which we are consuming the data in terabytes
The major problem is how do we read all this data from containers
The solutions we tried creating a 
1.Persistent Volume and Persistent Volume Claim of the NFS which according to us is not a feasible solution as the data grow we have to create a new pv and pvc and create deployment
2.Mounting volumes on Kubernetes if we do this there would be no difference between kubernetes and VMs
3.Adding docker volumes to containers we were able to add the volume but we cannot see the data in the container

How can we make the existing nfs as storage class and use it or how to mount all the 40+ NFS servers on pods

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need some form of object storage or block storage platform to manage the disks and automatically provisions disks for you.

You could use something like [Rook](https://rook.io/) for deploying [Ceph](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/intro/) into your cluster.

This will enable disk management in a much more friendly way, and help to automatically provision the NFS disks into your cluster.

Take a look at this: https://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/radosgw/nfs/

There is also the option of creating your own implementation using CRDs to trigger PV/PVC creation on certain actions/disks being mounted in your servers.